# How to submit multiple pieces of data at once with a Form

Tags: node.js, forms, mongodb, express

The question is worded awkwardly, so bear with me as I explain.

I am using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB.

Here is my backend code for a form submission:

```
router.post('/inputlog', function(req, res) {
Log.findOne({logTitle: req.body.logTitle}, function(err, existingLog) {
    if(!existingLog) {
        req.flash('errors', req.body.logTitle + ' was not found');
        return res.redirect('/inputlog');
    }
    if(existingLog) {
        Lot.findOneAndUpdate({logTitle: req.body.logTitle}, {
            $push: {
                OutdoorLogs: {
                    LogInput: {
                        logDate: req.body.logDate,
                        logInput: req.body.logInput
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {safe: true, upsert: false}, function (err, logSuccess) {
            if(err) {
                req.flash('errors', 'Log was not inserted due to Error.');
                return res.redirect('/inputlog');
            }
            if(logSuccess) {
                req.flash('success', req.body.logTitle+ ' Log has been updated. ');
                return res.redirect('/inputLog');
            }
        });
    }
})
});
```

So what is all this saying? Basically, I have a form to input logs. You first add a title for a log. It will then search the database (MongoDB) for the title of the log you inputted. If no such log title exists, it will send the user an error.

If the log title does exist, it will add a 'logDate' and 'logInput' into an array in that log title.

That's all well and good. BUT! What if I wanted to input *multiple* logs (multiple logDate's and logInput's) at the *same* time? The way I have the form set up, I can only input a new log into this array one at a time, and here is my form for reference:

```
<form method="POST" action="/inputlog">
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="logTitle">Log Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="logTitle" autofocus class="form-control uppercase" id="logTitle"/>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="logDate">Log Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="logDate" class="form-control logDate" id="logDate"/>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="logInput">log Input</label>
        <input type="text" name="logInput" class="form-control logInput" id="logInput"/>
     </div>
     <div class='form-group'>
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary pull-right" value="submit">
   </form>
```

So, again, the way this form is set up, I can only input one *log* at a time. If I want to input 20 different logs at once, I would have to do it all one at a time (input the log, hit submit, input the log, hit submit, etc...).

How can I input multiple logs (entries) with only one submit?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refactor the form, so that once one entry is complete, an additional set of inputs appears. I'd use `onblur` on every input that would check the form to make sure each input has some text, if it does run a function to add an additional form. Have an id for each form group that could correspond to an array index, and push an object with the fields in. This way, if it's edited later, they can be modified before submit.